# extract access taken variable from responds from server

Tags: php, curl

I am busy sending a HTTP curl request for request token , When i send the below code to get access token , when i receive the responds i would like the access token value and not entire responds.

```
 $params = array(
                'username' => 'nuser',
                'password' => 'password',
           
            );

$curlSecondHandler = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curlSecondHandler, [
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://localhost/api/v3/authentication/usernamepassword',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        'Content-Type: multipart/form-data',
        'Authorization: Bearer '
        
    ],
       CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params,
      

    
]);


$response2 = curl_exec($curlSecondHandler);
curl_close($curlSecondHandler);


$arr = json_decode($response2);

echo $response2->data -> accessToken ;
```

I get this error

Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: can you show us a var_dump of the $response2?

Comment: managed to fixed it